# Servlet forward to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have a servlet "ShowEvents", and I am trying to redirect to a jsp page "EventsOfClub.jsp" that is in WebContent folder. I am using Eclipse. But when I do the forward, nothing happens. I know this is a common mistake, but I browsed a lot of questions here and couldn't find the correct resource path (which I think is the problem). Please help.

ShowEvents:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("EventsOfClub.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**EDIT:** When the user logs in, I redirect (not forward) to ShowEvents servlet as:

```
response.sendRedirect("ShowEvents");
```

And then forward from ShowEvents to "EventsOfClub.jsp" as I said earlier. I thought the problem was I wasn't forwarding. But now when I forward from Login to ShowEvents as

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowEvents").forward(request, response);
```

I am getting the same problem, that is, it stays at Login and displays a blank page. (Before, ShowEvents was showing a blank page)

**EDIT:**
Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.EventsOfClub_jsp._jspService(EventsOfClub_jsp.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at ShowEvents.doPost(ShowEvents.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at Login.doPost(Login.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Login servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Enter credentials", urlPatterns = { "/Login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() 
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    //POST "localhost:8080/login"
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String name = (String) request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = (String) request.getParameter("password");

        Connection conn = null;
        String p="";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6666/Festeria", "postgres", "darthvedarvyas");

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("connection", conn);
            session.setAttribute("uname", name);

            Statement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

                    //some DB code

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(redirect);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg = "Oops! An error has occured! <br> Please try again.";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("msg", msg);
            response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show `EventsOfClub.jsp` and what code you have at line 82 of `ShowEvents.java` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hej Darth Vedar,

i made a very simple demo for you:

Here is the Servlet

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class EventsOfClubServlet
 */
@WebServlet(name = "events", urlPatterns = { "/events" })
public class EventsOfClubServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public EventsOfClubServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("EventsOfClub.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

Login Servlet

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet(name = "login", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if((userName != null && userName.equalsIgnoreCase("demo")) && (password != null && password.equalsIgnoreCase("123456"))) {
            response.sendRedirect("events");
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
        <label>Password:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="password"/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>EventsOfClub.jsp</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Still have the same problem: The servlet simply stays at ShowEvents.

Comment: Which URI you are calling in your Browser?

Comment: I am calling Login, which works fine. Once I forward to ShowEvents, it stays at Lgin and gives the NullPointerException

Comment: Can you update your queation and add ShowEvents Servlet and the JSPs code

Comment: And also the login.jsp and/or login servlet, there must be the mistake.

Comment: I have added the Login servlet. The "dispatcher" variable seems to be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet,

```
class ShowEvents{
      //----
      doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      doPost(request, response);
      }

      doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/EventsOfClub.jsp")
                                      .forward(request, response);
      }

}
```

Comment: This simply says resource not found. I don't think adding the context path helps here.

Comment: I noticed earlier that the / was missing. Even with the / it's not working, because the context path is already added. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your servlet? Do some System.out.println(""); before request.getRequestDispatcher(...) and check whether it prints in console or not. If still, problem may be in your web.xml or with eclipse.

Comment: NullPointerException when I forward. It's happening at Login AND ShowEvents. I have posted stack trace. Please help

Comment: Could you please post your web.xml?